# How to combine single row with array of data in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two table ad_post and ad_img . One ad_post row has many images in ad_img. I am trying to execute 2 queries together and than combine at the end. but 
table:`ad_images`
colums (`img_id`, `ad_id`, `img_name`) 
table : `ad_post`
colums(`id`, `user_id`, `title`, `price`, `cat`, `condit`, `description`, `vid`) 
Relationship
ad_post (1)------>(many)ad_images

```
public function read_ads()
{
    $this;
    $this->sql = 'SELECT ad_post.id,ad_post.user_id,ad_post.title,ad_post.price,
             sub_cat.s_cat_name,ad_post.condit,ad_post.description,ad_post.vid FROM  ad_post,sub_cat 
            where sub_cat.id=ad_post.cat';
    $sql1 = 'SELECT `img_id`,`img_name` FROM `ad_images` WHERE ad_id=?';
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare ( $this->sql );
    $stmt1 = $this->con->prepare ( $sql1 );

    if ($stmt === false) {
        trigger_error ( 'Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR );
    }
    // STMT
    $stmt->execute ();
    $stmt->store_result ();
    $stmt->bind_result ( $id, $uId, $title, $price, $cat, $usage, $desc, $vid );
    // STMT1

    // $ad =AdPost::__getAll('','','','','','','','');
    // $ad = Array();
    $img = Array ();
    $count = 0;
    $count = 0;
    $ads_img = Array ();
    $a_img = Array ();
    while ( $stmt->fetch () != NULL ) {

        $stmt1->bind_param ( 'i', $id );
        $stmt1->execute ();
        $stmt1->store_result ();
        $stmt1->bind_result ( $img_id, $img_name );
        while ( $stmt1->fetch () != NULL ) {
            echo $img_id;
            $a_img = Array (
                    'img_id' => $img_id,
                    'img_name' => $img_name 
            );
            try {
                $ads_img [$count] = $a_img;
            } catch ( Exception $exc ) {
                echo $exc->getTraceAsString ();
            }
        }
        $count ++;
        $ad_set = Array (
                'id' => $id,
                'uid' => $uId,
                'title' => $title,
                'price' => $price,
                'cat' => $cat,
                'usage' => $usage,
                'desc' => $desc,
                'img_name' => $a_img
        );
        try {
            $ads [$count] = $ad_set;
        } catch ( Exception $exc ) {
            echo $exc->getTraceAsString ();
        }

        $count ++;
    }

    $stmt->free_result ();
    $stmt->close ();

    return $ads;

}
```

I have got the ids of ads now i want to save imgs in array of $ad_set
The values of image array are returning null

Comment: And what is the problem? Blank screen? Unexpected output? Guess yourself?

Comment: images array values are null

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, I believe you need to use join to link queries

Comment: You query for images in `stmt1`. Try `while ($stmt1->fetch() != NULL) {}`

Comment: I used join but it gives repeated data .... I am trying to get id of each row from ad_post and then use that id to get array of image for each row of ad_post

Comment: stmt1 i tried but doesnt work...how can I use id of sql in sql1?

Comment: It's a very ugly way but you can loop your second query for each ID found in the first query

Comment: I hav updated the code ..node i just want to set array of images 
in ad_set array..which will make it multi dimenstional array